# Agency set the deadline for my requirements 2 days after they informed me about it

Tags: resignation, contracts

I recently got a job offer, and I'm currently working my 30 day notice period, with an end date of next week on Wednesday (15th).

The new employment agency only contacted me and gave the list of papers I need to submit just yesterday (the 8th) saying they need the response by July 11. There are a LOT of requirements, including medical results.

I still need to come in to my current job, so I don't have time to arrange all of the paperwork and testing required for my new job. I texted the agency, and they said it's ok to submit it by July 16. BUT the hr of the company I'm going to work for said "hopefully you can start on July 17".

Is that ok to be late responding to their requirements? Would that give the company a bad impression about me? Especially that I haven't even signed a contract? The contract will only be signed after I complete their requirements.

The other option is to expect my current employer to handle my absence while I sort the new company's requirements out. I mean I'm resigning anyway, but I'm sure that's a bad idea?

Comment: Please edit your question for grammar, punctuation and clarity. It is not clear what you're really asking.

Comment: You've done it wrong. Never resign from your current role until you've got a signed contract for your new role.

Comment: @PhilipKendall i know but the i asked for reassurance and the job really is for me and the agency will do the contract after i complete the requirements. but yes you are right, thats what im gonna do next time.

Comment: to add some useful info, this appears to be a follow on from http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/49176/does-it-really-take-long-to-sign-a-contract-after-saying-yes-to-verbal-offer, where the OP was being messed around by his/her agency, who were repeatedly promising to send paperwork 'soon'...

Comment: @yochannah i wont consider it "being messed around" haha. i think they were just slow on the process. but i guess i was wrong. i finally got contacted by the agency. They gave the start date already so thats a good thing.

Comment: Yay, glad to hear

Comment: As your company knows you are leaving how about asking them if they mind your using some work hours to accomplish some chores. If you have vacation days you could use one. If they need you to do lots of work to finalize your time with them offer  to put in extra time to make up for the time granted. You could even start your day early and leave early or perhaps use any lunch or break time to get a few things done.

Comment: Location matters here.  This is not india is it?

Comment: @MaxHaaksman Yeah i think i can do that since my actual work only takes like TWO hours. i do have lots of leaves but theyre gonna get cancelled once you render your resignation. but yeah im sure i can use my time. And also, the agency told me i can submit it until next saturday! cause my start date is suddenly a holiday and the HR moved it to monday! :)

Comment: @ReallyTiredOfThisGame No not india. Why?

Answer (score 0):

**I would consider it a potential red flag that they're *already* handing out loads of paperwork and giving short deadlines**. Lets face it, medical paperwork is NEVER going to get done in two days; just getting an appointment with a doctor usually takes about a week (unless they're providing you one). From personal experience, the only time I have ever been given that short of a deadline was for a drug test, and that was because they did it on the spot so I wouldn't have time to hide anything.

> Is that ok to be late responding to their requirements? Would that give the company a bad impression about me?

This is something that only the new company or agency can answer. If the agency gave you more time, I'd definitely use it. It might give them a bad impression of you, but if they revoke an offer because of their own ridiculous deadlines, good riddance. (It may not feel that way, but trust me, you don't want to work for a company like that.)

> The other option is to expect my current employer to handle my absence while I sort the new company's requirements out. I mean I'm resigning anyway, but I'm sure that's a bad idea?

You have nothing to really lose by doing this since you're already leaving, however it may give your current company a bad impression of you. If you decide to go this route, treat it like a vacation day--schedule it ahead of time, make sure all of your work is in good standing order, and that things won't fall apart just because you're gone. Honestly, it's good practice for when you've left anyway. If you can get the paperwork done in a day, I'd say it isn't a HUGE deal; if it's a week (especially out of a four week notice), it's a much bigger deal. If you absolutely cannot risk losing this new job, this is the better of the two options.

Comment: Just an update, the agency told me i can submit the requirements next week. And the HR moved my start date to Monday cause Friday is just announced a holiday. And also, you can apparently get medical results in one day. And the other requirements are the ones i already have.. So i think you can achieve it in 2 days.

Answer (score -1):

Did you tell the new company when you would be available? If you got the date wrong, contact them *now* and explain the delay; presumably they've run into that before. If they didn't ask it's definitely their fault and they should adjust. If you deliberately gave them the wrong date... well, now you see why you shouldn't do that; call them and claim it was an honest mistake.

If they aren't willing to make a small adjustment to your starting date, you're out of luck -- but that might suggest they'd be difficult people to work for in any case. Go back to job-hunting.

Comment: I told them my end date a few weeks ago when i said yes to their offer. Which is on July 15. Thats the end date on my current employer. 

But does the given time frame too short? Or is that normal?